# Why we are defining head node and new node differently in linked list

Tags: c, data-structures

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;

}; 



  void addstart (struct node **n, int new_data){
        struct node *new = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        new->data=new_data;
        new->next=*n;
        *n= new;
    }


int main(){
    struct node* head = NULL;
    addstart(&head,5); 
    return 0;
}
```

i just want to know if head_node is also a new_node and both are same data type struct node then why we are defining it simply as

```
struct node* head = NULL;
```

and other nodes as:

```
struct node *new = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Comment: look carefully. `head` is declared `NULL` at first, but later there is `*n=new`, which is assigning `head` the address to the first node

Comment: Those aren't definitions - those are assignments.

Comment: i want to know why we are not using malloc in head assignment case

Comment: But you are using malloc in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct node* head = NULL;
```

Because `head` is there to simply keeping track of the `head` of the list nothing else. Now don't the new node does the same?

yes it does. it keeps track of the memory that you allocate using `malloc` and then  you point it out with subsequent node's `next` attribute.

`head` is of same type as `newnode` and both are same functonally. but we put a different meaning to `head` in that - we are making it point to the `head` of th list rather than making it a local variable which we can throw away.

#### Then also why `head = NULL`?

Ah! that's because we always create a node and make it's next attribute to point to the current `head` and then we change head to make the new node part of our linked list.

Initially the first node should be

```
+----+
|  +------+
+----+    |
          V
         NULL (Well to make this NULL we just make head = NULL initially)
```

#### i want to know why we are not using malloc in head assignment case..

Because it's not needed - as simple as that. Why should we allocate an extra memory space and then assign it to `head` when the purpose of `head` is to just point to already allocated node. And when we add another extra node we add it to the `head` of the linked list and make it head. it's nothing other than pointing to the beginning of the list. That's it.

---

`new` is not a good variable name. Try some good one. Think a bit before naming a variable it will save you a lot of time in future.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you declare head it doesn't have anything to point to yet, it indicates the list is empty , as soon as data is added it can point to the first node in the list.